# Cannot ping or nslookup local Wordpress

Tags: ubuntu, localhost, wordpress

Hi I have created a local WordPress blog using lamp server. I can ping and nslookup localhost, however; i cannot do the same with localhost/WordPress 
Help please

Comment: You can't ping or nslookup a URL.

Comment: It says connection timed out; no servers could be reached.

Comment: Are you running `nslookup localhost/WordPress`? If so, that is a URL. You can't nslookup a URL.

Comment: I need to figure out if I can access my WordPress with my terminal

Comment: You're not answering my question. Are you trying to run `nslookup localhost/WordPress`?

Comment: yes I was trying nslookup localhost/wordpress

Comment: OK then as I said, you cannot nslookup a URL. If you're trying to access the /WordPress site and it is not the default web site then you'll need to set up name-based virtual hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not? What happens? Your question is lacking some critical details. What output do you get from the commands when you try and run them? Does any connectivity work or is it just ping/DNS that is failing?

Comment: It says connection timed out; no servers could be reached.